# MFC C++ differentiate between two devices from WM_DEVICECHANGE notifications

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, usb

I am coding a function to detect addition/removal of USB devices using C++ VS2019 in windows. [WM_DEVICECHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange) gives notification when a device is removed or connected to PC, but it gives multiple notifications for a single device. The parameters that are returned through are also same for all notifications.

The problem is When 2 devices are connected or removed just one after another, the number of notifications increases but the parameters remains the same. How can i differentiate that the notifications are from different devices.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCheckDlg, CDialogEx)
   ON_MESSAGE(WM_DEVICECHANGE, &CCheckDlg::OnMyDeviceChange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The function:

```
    LRESULT CCheckDlg::OnMyDeviceChange(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        //When USB device connected or removed,
        //The wParam is always equal to 7 and lParam is equal to 0.
    }
```

Or, if there is any other way to detect device addition/removal using C++, you can suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `wParam` of the [WM_DEVICECHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/wm-devicechange) message contains the particular event that triggered this message. A value of `7` refers to the `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` event.

The documentation for [DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/dbt-devnodes-changed) explains:

> There is no additional information about which device has been added to or removed from the system. Applications that require more information should register for device notification using the [RegisterDeviceNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationw) function.